# Why do some users on my Google contacts list have the ability to be added to circles

Tags: google-plus, google-contacts

I was going through my contacts on the Google contacts app. For some reason I have some contacts I can add to my Google+ circles and others I cannot. Any idea why not?

[image: screen shot from Contacts]

Comment: Do they have a Gmail address?

Comment: yes they do.. that's what's confusing me (further more, some of the people i can add in a circle don't even have a gmail account.. they got hotmail or something)

Comment: At a guess, I'd say the ones with Gmail accounts that you can't add have either deleted their Google+ profiles, or have set their privacy so that people can't add them to Circles. It's also possible, though probably unlikely, that they've blocked you on G+.

Comment: Aren’t Google+ and Gmail accounts decoupled now? I don’t think there is any correlation between having either one of them like there used to be. I’d say the contacts you can add to Circles have that email address registered with a Google+ account, whereas those you can’t don’t.

Comment: @Phong: Yes, they are, but most people go with defaults. Further, if you have a Google account (which all Gmail users have) it's one click to create a G+ profile. For others, you need to create the Google account first; can't have a G+ profile without a Google account.

Answer (score -4):

After read your question, I just want suggest to you read a manual help support from *Google apps/contact or G+*. About add people to your circle from contact.

I just found this https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047805?hl=en&rd=1&authuser=0.

Google says, any some limit for adding people to your circle on a day. So you must wait for a next day to do again. I copy this for you:

## Limits on circles

- You can add up to 5,000 profiles and pages across all of your circles. There is a daily limit for how many people and pages you can add to your circles. If you reach the limit, just wait a day to add more people or pages.

This my own contact, and I find too some of friends I can't add to my G+ circle.

[image: screenshoot my contact]

After I look for detail, my friend not using Google product (or) account. So absolutely I cant add them to my circle.

Hope you can get more answer after reading rule or mechanism about how the Google apps work from link I choose it for you.

Comment: _my friend not using Google product (or) account. So absolutely I cant add them to my circle._ You can but they can't. When you will add they will get an invitation.